# Easy way to connect XBox controller to MATLAB program and record input?

Tags: matlab, controller, xbox

I am trying to implement an XBox controller into a cognitive science lab I am working in. The goal is to use the controller in place of a keyboard or number pad to replicate a previous study that needs user input.

Each button/trigger would correlate with an int, and include vibration would be great.

Not sure where to start, but any advice would be greatly appreciated!